# Hide modal window generated by showModalDialog in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have this page:

```
<body>
    <script>
        function showModal() {

            // do some things here...

            var address = 'http://localhost:61948/modal.aspx';
            window.showModalDialog(address);
        }
    </script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="btnModal" type="button" value="button" onclick="showModal();" /></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

And then I have a WebBrowser that clicks on this button.

```
public Form1()
{
    string url = "http://localhost:61948/WebForm1.aspx";
    InitializeComponent();
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
    webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
}

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("btnModal").InvokeMember("click");
}
```

The problem is that I shouldn't show the modal, and yet I have to click on the button. I've tried to cancel the event using newWindow event but this event is not fired in this situation. 
The real application is a console application and I can't show anything, then I have hide the browser, but the modal window is being shown to the user. And I can't change anything on server side. I just have to hide this modal window from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new Object[] { "window.showModalDialog = null;" });
```

If you want to display the dialog elsewhere you could [change `window.showModalDialog` to `window.external.showModalDialog`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.inetsdk.programming.webbrowser_ctl/5e60qREbFq8/Jus9C9IPfAkJ) and implement a `showModalDialog` method in your object for scripting.

Comment: It worked, but I've set the web browser property ScriptErrorsSuppressed to true, otherwise IE shows the script error window. Thanks!

Comment: The script error could also be avoided by changing window.showModalDialog to an actual function that has the same signature with the original